# Reference request: probability distributions + rigorous derivation of results (including densities!)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request

I am looking for a detailed book on probability distributions themselves.

It should have a long list of common probability distributions, it should speak of why they are useful for what particular application, and it should explain/prove why the definition of the distribution (i.e., the density function or mass function) actually does what it is supposed to do, and it should then derive key results such as moments, etc.

It is in particular the explanation of where the density comes from that I am interested in.

Is there such a book, or is one forced to read the original papers where the distributions were first introduced (which I would rather not do, since those papers are usually written in more advanced language, and it is more neat to have a single source than dozens of different ones).

Comment: I feel like any good application-oriented intro book on probability will do this, eg Ross.

Answer (score 1):

- Univariate Discrete Distributions, 3rd Edition by Norman L. Johnson, Adrienne W. Kemp, Samuel Kotz
- Continuous Univariate Distributions, Volume 1, 2nd Edition by Norman L. Johnson, Samuel Kotz, N. Balakrishnan
- Continuous Univariate Distributions, Volume 2, 2nd Edition
  by Norman L. Johnson, Samuel Kotz, N. Balakrishnan
- Discrete Multivariate Distributions by Norman L. Johnson, Samuel Kotz, N. Balakrishnan
- Continuous Multivariate Distributions, Volume 1: Models and Applications, 2nd Edition by Samuel Kotz, N. Balakrishnan, Norman L. Johnson

Comment: Well, they are rather EXPENSIVE... :-(